# Facebook-like comment refresh system?

Tags: php, comments

I've recently built a simple messaging system for some work colleagues and I am currently working on optimizing current functionality. Many users are complaining of a messy-looking message display system.

The thing that I currently have in place is a PHP file inside of an iFrame that refreshes every 15 seconds. However this is undesirable and wastes resources.

As a result I was wondering if there are any tutorials out there that propose better methods, similar to those used by Facebook whereby the comment is automatically loaded upon posting.

Comment: keyword: __"websocket"__

Answer (score -1, accepted):

http://ajaxim.com/ <-- Ajax Instant Messaging framework. :)

**EDIT :**

You might also want to try this http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/05/09/building-real-time-commenting-system/ which is a good that guides you through making a realtime comment system.
That system is built using HTML 5. (PHP and Ajax too of course) And it's using **Websockets** :)

Oh, and a link to a previously asked question that is similar:
[Instant notification using php/mysql,please give me a general idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9939381/instant-notification-using-php-mysql-please-give-me-a-general-idea)

Comment: Don't answers questions with just links... [answer]

Comment: I'm sorry, but he asked for tutorials. "As a result I was wondering if there are any tutorials out there that propose better methods, similar to those used by Facebook whereby the comment is automatically loaded upon posting."